# Vue 2 Unknown custom element on vue libraries

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a few libraries in my vue project like `FusionCharts`, `VueProgressBar` etc. But I get this error in my console:

```
Unknown custom element: <vue-progress-bar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
2vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <fusioncharts> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Here's my `main.js` where I use `Vue.use()` to incorporate these libraries in my app:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { firestorePlugin } from "vuefire";
import Notifications from "vue-notification";
import VueProgressBar from "vue-progressbar";

// Include Dependencies
import VueFusionCharts from "vue-fusioncharts";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import Column2D from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";

import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import "./style.scss";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");

Vue.use(Notifications);
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
  color: "rgb(143, 255, 199)",
  failedColor: "red",
  height: "2px"
});
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);
//More code here
```

Why I'm getting this error even after properly importing and using these libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of code. You are creating a new Vue instance which does not have the component vue-progress-bar:

```
Vue.use(Notifications);
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
  color: "rgb(143, 255, 199)",
  failedColor: "red",
  height: "2px"
});
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```